# Date validation using moment.js is not giving error on giving invalid date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, momentjs

I am doing validation using angular js. For date validation, I am using the `moment.js` file. My issue is when I am entering the date which is having a year as '0000' e.g. 1-1-0000, it is not giving the error. My directive code is below-

```
app.directive("validDate", function () {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "A", // Attributes only
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.cValidDate = function(value) {
            if (value === undefined || value === null || value === "") {
                return true;
            }

            return moment(value, ["D-M-YYYY"], true).isValid();
        }
    }
}
});
```

Can anybody help me in my validation? I have created a plunker here- 
[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/S9usP0nCCDQ0Ja6gQaNf?p=preview)

I have edited the script, 
But still it is now giving error for all dates less than 1-1-1970, because it is taking date 1-1-0001 as 1-1-1970 so it is validation according to it, 
also when no value is there in date, date is shown as invalid untill and unless I enter the date greater than 1-1-1970. 
I wanted that if year is 0000 date should not be valid. Can anybody help me? I have updated my plunker with the above code.

Update-

Now I am able to resolve the date issue  but my problem is now that- 
 if date is empty still the error is there I don't want this error when date is empty, what condition should I put for this? Please see my updated plunker.

**Answer-**

I am able to made my answer, as I added the below condition -

```
    if(moment(value, ["D-M-YYYY"], true).isValid()){ 
               // condition
} else 
    return true;
```

see my new plunker here- https://plnkr.co/edit/uKcynQktBCKRYoN7xdM1?p=preview

Comment: `0000` is a valid year as per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years), for your specific needs you might need to add extra check before `moment().isValid()` call, checking for year and returning `Invalid` if its `0000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native JS Date object thinks there is a year zero as well. Year zero is acceptable per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years), which uses astronomical year numbering. In this system, year 0 = 1 BCE, year -1 = 2 BCE, and so forth.

This is not true for many databases. So better set a date must be greater than validation in the subject you need.

```
if(moment(value, ["D-M-YYYY"], true).isValid())
            {

              //alert(moment(value, ["D-M-YYYY"], true).isSameOrAfter(moment("1-1-0001"), ["D-M-YYYY"], true));
              if(moment(value, ["D-M-YYYY"]).isSameOrAfter(moment("1-1-0000"), ["D-M-YYYY"]) )
                return true ;
              else
                return false;
            }else
            {
              return false;
            }
```

Comment: But I want to add validation for year '0000' as invalid date, what should I do for achieving that.

Comment: Add a validation that date should be greater than or equal to 1-1-0001

Comment: I am unable to do validation for date 1-1-1001, beacuse its reading as 1-1-1970,

Comment: I updated my plunker and question as well, i added logic for date less than 1-1-0001 is invalid, but its not working. can you please see it

Comment: I think your plunker working. Can you give for which date its not working now

Comment: yea I did some changes , now its working for date less than 1-1-1970, Thanks a lot !

Comment: But my issue is that if date is empty still the error is there-isYearInvalid":true, I dont want this error, what condition should I put for this?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add a function that checks for the value of the year alone. My solution is not elegant but it does the trick.

```
function checkYear (v) {
  v = v.split("-");
  if(v[2] === "0000"){
    return true;
  }
  /* or you could go for a year of your choice*/
  /*
  if(parseInt(v[2]) <= 1900){
    return true;
  }
  */
}
```